# PowerShell show elapsed time

Tags: powershell, timer

I have a script that kicks off an event and waits for the user to press any key to stop the script execution. I was trying to find a way to show a timer (how long the script has been running) while waiting for user input at [Read-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849945.aspx). Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

This works

```
$Time = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($true) {
    $CurrentTime = $Time.Elapsed
    write-host $([string]::Format("`rTime: {0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}",
                                  $CurrentTime.hours,
                                  $CurrentTime.minutes,
                                  $CurrentTime.seconds)) -nonewline
    sleep 1
    if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and ("q" -eq $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("IncludeKeyUp,NoEcho").Character)) {
        Write-Host "Exiting now"
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here for using WPF UI in backgound in powershell http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2008/05/23/BackgroundTimerPowerShellWPFWidget

Answer (score 42):

This gave me the output I was after :)

```
$StartTime = $(get-date)

$elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $StartTime

$totalTime = "{0:HH:mm:ss}" -f ([datetime]$elapsedTime.Ticks)
```

Answer (score 19):

From the article [Measuring Elapsed Time in Powershell](http://poshtips.com/2010/03/30/measuring-elapsed-time-in-powershell/) ([archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20111217164222/http://poshtips.com/2010/03/30/measuring-elapsed-time-in-powershell)):

> Assuming that the variable `$script:StartTime` was set at the
>   beginning of your script, elapsed time can be determined using either
>   of the following methods:
>
> `$elapsedTime = new-timespan $script:StartTime $(get-date)`
>
> or
>
> `$elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $script:StartTime`
>
> Both methods work exactly the same and produce a `System.TimeSpan` object.

So, using the above example, you could set `$script:StartTime` before Read-Host and then call
 `$elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $script:StartTime` after.

Comment: Right, that much I understand, but I wanted to see if it is possible to show a running clock while waiting at the Read-Host prompt.

Comment: your link to poshtips.com is dead

Answer (score 7):

Using a timer class (RIP poshtips) gave me something like this:

```
$Time = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($NoEvent) {
    $CurrentTime = $Time.Elapsed
    write-host $([string]::Format("`rTime: {0:d2}:{1:d2}:{2:d2}",
                                  $CurrentTime.hours,
                                  $CurrentTime.minutes,
                                  $CurrentTime.seconds)) -nonewline
    sleep 1

    #Handle event
    if(event){$NoEvent = false}
}
```

Where $NoEvent is your event/boolean (key press func, etc.).

Comment: diagnostics.stopwatch is buggy, fwiw

Comment: The link is broken (the domain no longer exists).

Comment: RIP poshtips, I'll remove the link.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 5):

I'm happy with this little function expanded on from Xelco52's answer

```
$startTime = $(get-date)
write-host "Elapsed:00:00:00"
$NoEvent = $true
While ($NoEvent)
{
  Start-Sleep 1
  $elapsedTime = new-timespan $startTime $(get-date)
  write-host "Elapsed:$($elapsedTime.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss"))"  

  #Handle event
  if(event){$NoEvent = $false} 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR answer**

```
$StartTime = $(get-date)
#...do something...
$elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $StartTime
```

Most of the times `$elapsedTime.TotalSeconds` or `$elapsedTime.TotalMilliseconds` is what you want.